# Python video editing -- How to trim videos

Tags: python, video, video-processing

Is there an easy way to trim a video file in python. If I know the start time and end time, I want to save the new file as multiple shorter files based on input.

example pseudo code:

```
function cut_video(original_vid, start, stop):
    original_vid.start_time(start)
    original_vid.end_time(stop)
    original_vid.trim() #based on times
    new_vid = original_vid
    return new_vid
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
def get_ffmpeg_bin():
    ffmpeg_dir = helper_functions.get_ffmpeg_dir_path()
    FFMPEG_BIN = os.path.join(ffmpeg_dir, "ffmpeg.exe")
    return FFMPEG_BIN


def split_vid_from_path(video_file_path, start_time, durration):
    ffmpeg_binary =  get_ffmpeg_bin()
    output_file_name = get_next_file_name(video_file_path)
    pipe = sp.Popen([ffmpeg_binary,"-v", "quiet", "-y", "-i", video_file_path, "-vcodec", "copy", "-acodec", "copy",
                 "-ss", start_time, "-t", durration, "-sn", output_file_name ])


    pipe.wait()
    return True


sample_vid = os.path.join(get_sample_vid_dir_path(), "Superman-01-The_Mad_Scientist.mp4")
split_vid_from_path(sample_vid, "00:00:00", "00:00:17")
```

https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html -> this documentation allows you to add your own custom flags to your ffmpeg wrapper.

Something to note, you may want to verify the user is giving you valid data.

Comment: This works great, except the third argument in 'split_vid_from_path' seems to be duration rather than 'end_time'.

Comment: You may be right about that. I'll have to look it up to verify

Answer (score 0):

A nice module to do these kinds of things is **moviepy**.

Example:

```py
from moviepy.editor import *

video = VideoFileClip("myHolidays.mp4").subclip(50,60)

# Make the text. Many more options are available.
txt_clip = ( TextClip("My Holidays 2013",fontsize=70,color='white')
             .set_position('center')
             .set_duration(10) )

result = CompositeVideoClip([video, txt_clip]) # Overlay text on video
result.write_videofile("myHolidays_edited.webm",fps=25) # Many options...
```

The documentation of this module can be found at https://pypi.org/project/moviepy/